# Using structured json to determine truthy logic, how can I ultimately return a boolean with using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Considering the following `JSON` example of logic, where when you see the `value` prop it is deriving its value from user input and comparing that against the expression:

```
{
  "truthy": [
    [
      "AND",
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "fname",
        "expression": "John"
      },
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "lname",
        "expression": "Doe"
      }
    ],
    "OR",
    {          
      "operator": "=",
      "compareType": "boolean",
      "value": "Agree",
      "expression": true
    },
    "OR",
    [
      "AND",
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "fname",
        "expression": "Jane"
      },
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "lname",
        "expression": "Doe"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The translated expression would be:

```
(fname === "John" && lname === "Doe") || agree === true || (fname === "Jane" && lname === "Doe")
```

Right now what I'm doing is iterating over the structure and pushing values to an array, and later using `eval` to return `true` or `false`.

```
for (i; i < v.length; i++) {

  if (Array.isArray(v[i])) {
    e.push("(true===");
    e.push(this.parseBlocks(v[i], a, 0));
    e.push(")");
  } else if (v[i] === "OR") {
    e.push("||");
  } else if (v[i] === "AND") {
    e.push("&&");
  } else {
    e.push(true);
    e.push("===");
    e.push(this.parseBlocks([v[i]], a, 0));
  }
}

return eval(e.join(""));
```

This works great, but was wondering if there would be a more precise way of handling this without building an expression to pass into `eval`?

The expression that the above code would generate if first name was John and last name was Doe and the checkbox (i.e. Agree) was not checked would be:

```
eval("(true === true) || true === false || (true === false)")
```

I didn't need to construct this string to evaluate when it was a simpler expression. For example, the two OR strings in between everything.

The code not included is the actual parsing function, but what it does is takes the first element in the array (i.e. "AND", "OR") and uses that to determine if that particular block of logic returns true or false.

How could this be handled with the consideration of potential deeper nesting of logic, to determine the outcome without using eval, or considering I'm controlling what's being passed into eval perhaps it may provide better performance in comparison?

Requirements:

1. I need to keep the current JSON format of the actual conditions as previous functionality relies on it. The inclusion of "AND", "OR", how and where that is placed before, between, after, is optional as I try to find a more concise way of dealing with it.
2. No, this cannot be done in SQL or other server-side methods

Inspiration:

1. Found [this](https://github.com/jwadhams/json-logic-js) which has a different structure but supports deeper nesting and complex structure so trying to understand how to adapt my existing solution to handle things similar.

Comment: where do you get `value` from?

Comment: the value prop points to a form control (i.e. input) so in the parser it compares the user inputed value to the expression. Think of it like `document.getElementById(condition.value)` to access it and compare its value to what's in the expression.

Comment: whar result are you expecting? why do you have different structures,, like prefix and infix? can you use a common style?

Comment: I can change anything as far as structure goes except for the actual object that represents a single unit of logic, such as the block that has compareType, operator, etc. In fact I should update my requirements as the "new" stuff can change. My thought was to use a surrounding array to represent `( ... )`, and as it looped through the items if it found a simple string such as "AND" or "OR" it would represent && or ||. The structure makes sense when constructing a string that's passed through `eval` but not sure if that's the best way to handle it.

Comment: i would suggest a consistent syntax, depending on the input. basically a decision between prefix or infix but not both.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you need two functions:

- one to parse the general structure of the json with objects, arrays, ... This is my `evaluate`
- one to evaluate the final objects. This is my `leafValue`

---

## 1 - `leafValue`

This one is the most straightforward. You just need a set of data to evaluate from. Here I created an object called `data` but in your question you seem to want to get the values from current scope (`fname` as opposed to `someObject.fname`) so you could just as well replace my `data` with `this`.

I then implemented a simple `switch / case` to potentially account for different `operator` values. You would need to complicate this a little bit if you also want to implement more complex `compareType` options, but luckily here, JS is pretty forgiving if we don't use the strict identity `===`.

In the end, most of the logic is here:

```
return data[item.value] === item.expression
```

---

## 2 - `evaluate`

This one is a little trickier. I implemented a depth-first recursive function that will flatten the initial json object iteration by iteration.

1. Every item that is an `Array` has to go through `evaluate` first before it can be useful (depth-first and recursive)
2. in the order of the array, the first 3 items must always contain 1 combinator (`"OR"` or `"AND"`) and 2 values (a previous value calculated by `evaluate`, or the result of an object passed through `leafValue`). `evaluate` finds which is which, and applies the logical operation.
3. in the array I'm currently evaluating, `evaluate` replaces the first 3 items with the result of step 2.
4. Repeat from step 2. If there aren't enough items left, `evaluate` returns the single value left in the array.

---

For neatness, I wrapped the both of them in a `processData` function.

```js
function processData(data, json) {
  const combinators = ["OR", "AND"]

  function leafValue(item) {
    switch (item.operator) {
      case '=':
        return data[item.value] === item.expression
    }
    throw new Error(`unknown comparison operator ${item.operator}`)
  }

  function evaluate(json) {
    const evaluated = json.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? evaluate(item) : item)
    while (evaluated.length >= 3) {
      const chunk = [evaluated[0], evaluated[1], evaluated[2]]
      const combinator = chunk.find(item => combinators.includes(item))
      const [A, B] = chunk.filter(item => !combinators.includes(item))
      const valueA = typeof A === 'boolean' ? A : leafValue(A)
      const valueB = typeof B === 'boolean' ? B : leafValue(B)
      const result = combinator === 'OR' ?
        (valueA || valueB) :
        (valueA && valueB)
      evaluated.splice(0, 3, result)
    }
    return evaluated[0]
  }

  return evaluate(json)
}

const json = {
  "truthy": [
    [
      "AND",
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "fname",
        "expression": "John"
      },
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "lname",
        "expression": "Doe"
      }
    ],
    "OR",
    {
      "operator": "=",
      "compareType": "boolean",
      "value": "Agree",
      "expression": true
    },
    "OR", [
      "AND",
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "fname",
        "expression": "Jane"
      },
      {
        "operator": "=",
        "compareType": "text",
        "value": "lname",
        "expression": "Doe"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

const data = {
  fname: 'John',
  lname: 'Doe',
}

const result = processData(data, json.truthy)
console.log(result)
```